# Still possible to extract video clip between bookmarks in VLC 1.1.3?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, video-editing

According to [this blog post](http://angelb.wordpress.com/2007/06/07/using-bookmarks-to-extract-a-clip-of-media-using-vlc-brief-tutorial/), back in 2007 or so VLC used to have the convenient ability to extract the clip between two bookmarks.

This would be phenomenally useful, but I don't see any sort of "Extract" button appear in the bookmark window or anywhere else as described when I select two bookmarks. (I'm using VLC 1.1.3 on Debian/Squeeze to play a transport stream from a Freeview PVR).

Is the functionality disappeared, or just hiding from me ?

(Note: I'm not interested in general recommendations for non-linear video editing tools I could use to chop up video; but I am interested in any other "players" which have a convenient GUI-accessible clip extractor which doesn't reencode the stream.  Nearest I-frame accuracy is fine.)

Comment: still an issue in Vlc 2, they seem to have removed a lot of features... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a (fairly ugly) workround for the above... the VLC bookmarks window does report the byte offset from the start of the file, so I can actually do

```
dd bs=1 skip=<start> count=<end-start> if=video.ts of=extract.ts
```

to get the extract, but it would be a lot nicer to do it from the GUI.  (Although I have just discovered - too late - it's possible to copy-paste the large numbers involved from the bookmark info rather than retyping them :^)